# SSAS : How to automate cube processing and user role attribution?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ssis, ssas

I've been having to give a role to new users, problem I have to add them to 2 different cubes in 6 different environments, which is 12 times adding the user and processing the rights table, which amounts to around an hour on my company's rather weak laptop, for EVERY new user.

Is there any way to juste write some code with a list of users you wanna add to a list of cubes, and you'd just tell it to process the table after each addition ? It'd be a real life saver right now.

Comment: Is there a relationship between processing a table and adding users to a role?  Or are you asking how do you automate to separate tasks?

Comment: Also, is this tabular or multi-dimensional

Comment: @MarkWojciechowicz the work I'm supposed to do requires me to process the access rights table after each user addition, which gets pretty long and repetitive especially on a low end company laptop. And it's tabular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SSIS, you can use the Analysis Services Execute DDL Task.  This can take a [TMSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/tmsl/tabular-model-scripting-language-tmsl-reference?view=asallproducts-allversions) script as input, which would look like below.

1) **sequence** - this command allows you to perform multiple operations

2) **createOrReplace** - this will refresh the role with the new list of members.  Note that every existing member needs to be included in the role or they will be wiped out

3) **refresh** - processes the table

In ssis, you might create a connection to each environment and loop through a set of script files, so that you would not need to modify the package to add new members.

However, I would also suggest switching to an AD group instead of adding explicit users to the role.  Then you would only need to refresh table.

```
{
    "sequence": {
        "operations": [{
                "createOrReplace": {
                    "object": {
                        "database": "<Your Database>",
                        "role": "<Your Role Name>"
                    },
                    "role": {
                        "name": "Reader",
                        "modelPermission": "read",
                        "members": [{
                                "memberName": "<Your Domain>\\<User 1>",
                                "memberName": "<Your Domain>\\<User 2>",
                                <All the users in the role...>
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }, {
                "refresh": {
                    "type": "full",
                    "objects": [{
                            "database": "<Your Database>",
                            "table": "<Your Table>"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to have this code add a user to a pre-existing role instead of creating a new role ? Thanks nonetheless !

Comment: There’s no command to add to a role, it just replaces the whole thing each time. In your case you would need to keep track of the users and add to the list as you go. I’d also consider using AD groups instead which would avoid this altogether.